# Java XML to JSON using XMLSerializer making root element an Array

Tags: java, json, xmlserializer

Given that I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <op>update</op>
    <path>someString</path>
    <value>12345</value>
</Root>
```

and I want this output in JSON:

```
[{ "op":"update", "path":"someString", "value":"12345" }]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
package jsonconvertor;
import net.sf.json.JSON;
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer;

public class JSONConvertor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root><op>update</op><path>someString</path><value>12345</value></Root>";
        String output = "";

        XMLSerializer xml = new XMLSerializer();
        JSON jObj = xml.read( input );
        output = jObj.toString();

        System.out.println("My JSON:\n" + output);
    }
}
```

When I run that code I get the following response:

```
{"op":"update","path":"someString","value":"12345"}
```

However you will notice that the leading '[' and closing ']' are missing.

When I try changing the XML "input" string in the code to the following:

```
String input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root class=\"object\"><op>update</op><path>someString</path><value>12345</value></Root>";
```

which makes sense since itRoot was an object to start with, so I tried changing the "input" string to "array":

```
String input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root class=\"array\"><op>update</op><path>someString</path><value>12345</value></Root>";
```

however then I get the following:

```
["update","someString","12345"]
```

What am I missing?  I want the output I get when class="object" however I want it enclosed in square brackets.  I want the output to look like the example at the top of the post.

Comment: Try with this : String input2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root class=\"array\"><SubRoot class=\"object\"><op>update</op><path>someString</path><value>12345</value></SubRoot></Root>";

Comment: I can't thank you enough! .. This is the solution to my problem!  I will certainly accept this as the solution I was looking for if you add it again as an answer!

Comment: Yes I've added as answer you can accept it . Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this input String it should work :

```
String input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root class=\"array\"><SubRoot class=\"object\"><op>update</op><path>someString</path><value>12345</value></SubRoot></Root>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the given XML, you have only 1 `ROOT` element , so it's a single `JSONObject` and not a `JSONArray`. So, if you want a `JSONArray` as Output, you should provide `XML Array` as input to the `xml.read( input )` method.

If your input looks like below, you will get your desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <SubRoot>
         <op>update</op>
         <path>someString</path>
         <value>12345</value>
    <SubRoot>
</Root>
```

**Output :**

```
[{"op":"update","path":"someString","value":"12345"}]
```

Comment: Thank you, however when adding

    String input = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Root><SubRoot><op>update</op><path>someString</path><value>12345</value></SubRoot></Root>";

I get the following result:

    {"SubRoot":["update","someString","12345"]}

Comment: OMG. But i am getting the output i pasted here which looks same as you. I think the difference is because of the dependency jar version's.Let me check again

Comment: @Deepak Gunasekaran try to add `class="array"` to `Root`.

Comment: Okay @Samabcde . Thanks :)